# Как реализуется "общак" для всех платежных методов, если пользователь хочет вывести средства?

Tags: api, платежи

Подключил несколько платежных методов. Например, sberbank, yandex, qiwi. Пользователь может как пополнять, так и выводить средства. Пополнять, соответственно, может любым из предложенных способов. Вопрос, как реализуется "общак" для всех платежных методов, когда пользователь хочет вывести средства ?

Например, баланс qiwi - 100, баланс yandex - 50, баланс sberbank - 10. Пользователь хочет вывести 150 р. через киви.

Таким образом получается, что qiwi должен обратиться к балансам каждого из доступных методов пополнения и выяснить, кто из них располагает "удобной" суммой для запроса перевода на самого себя. Т.е qiwi запрашивает баланс ЯД и проверяет, удовлетворяет ли ответ условию. Если да, то ЯД переводит 50р на киви, и киви отдает пользователю 150р.

Правильно я понимаю ? (Извиняюсь, если объяснил на марсианском)

Answer (score 0):

никак, понятие общяка это только ваше представление, а в платежах это отдельные счета и если вы хотите вывести деньги со счета, то нужно что на нем было достаточно средств если нет то пополнить его переводом из одного кошелька на другой. Делать это в автоматическом режиме не рекомендуется в силу того что пользователь не просил вас делать ту или иную транзакцию без его ведома. Чем больше движений тем больше услуга по платежам. Рекомендации всегда такие, что держите на счетах ровно сколько сколько надо иначе будут излишние расходы по переводам средств.

Comment: Я указал, что пользователь, цитирую - хочет вывести 150р через киви. У меня был реализован этот самый терминологический "общак" для 2х методов - ЯД и КИВИ. Все работает безупречно, но вопрос в том, корректно ли это или нет. Вручную пополнять, например, 15 счетов..отслеживать каждую транзакцию пользователей и проверять, хватит ли средств на счете - ну не смешите вы меня ))

Comment: 15 счетов это не много, а переводить со счета на счет стоит денег. Если вам смешно можете настроить всё на автомат и пусть снимает. Вы же говорите о недостатках средств и то что qiwi  должен будет запросить средства из остальных счетов это тоже нормально но операция по овердрафту считается не зря рискованной. Допустим вместо 150 вы запросите jошибочно 1500 тогда qiwi почистит все счета?

Comment: Ошибочно он запросит 1500 только в том случае, если непосредственно вы скажете ему столько запросить. Самовольно он 1500, при переданном параметре в 150 ну никак не сможет запросить. Даже если и произойдет сбой и он обратится к другим счетам, чтобы набрать нужную сумму - никто не пострадает ведь. По поводу "перевод со счета на счет стоит денег"(2% комиссия) - не деньги. Тем более, если сайт окупает этот порог в несколько раз.

Comment: Я указал проблему с оведрафтом и то что она считается более рискованной. Переводить или нет ваше дело. Спросили правильно или нет я вам ответил.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, приму к сведению